# Match range of device-pixel-ratios

Tags: css

I have three different spritesheets, one for 1:1 resolution, @2, @3.

When I initially coded my stylesheet, I put the standard sprites in the global namespace, then did the following for the retina images.

`@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (   -moz-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (   min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (   -ms-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (     -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1),
only screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 192dpi),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 2dppx)`

The issue with this is both the @1 and @2 spritesheets are downloaded for users at that resolution. If I were to encapsulate the @1 styles, I would have to match a slew of ratios, such as 1.25, 1.3, 1.5 etc.

Is there a way to match device-pixel-ratio of 0-2, and apply a style to it?

EDIT: Just to note, I would like to keep this completely CSS; i'm aware of various methods to do this in javascript.

Comment: You can match ratio > xx

Comment: @Huangism If you could give a working example as an answer, I would gladly accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this

```
@media screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5)
```

You can just set the minimum. At my work we just set the minimum, you can just say min is bigger than 1.2 for example and use the x2 image for anything above 1.2.

There is also a max-device-pixel-ratio if you really want to do ranges but I don' think it is needed

```
@media (min-device-pixel-ratio:1.2) and (max-device-pixel-ratio:2)
```

that's a range of 1.2 - 2

Comment: You're right - For some reason, I thought it was forced. Thanks! http://jsfiddle.net/h4XGT/2/ for future readers.